# how to conbine the following two query

Tags: mysql, sql

the following query no.1 and query no.2 are working each line..
1.

```
SELECT app_user.au_userid, SUM(order_detail.od_quantity), (order_detail.od_quantity*SUM(order_detail.od_subtotal)) AS total_amount FROM app_user JOIN orders ON app_user.au_id = orders.o_au_id JOIN order_detail ON orders.o_id = order_detail.od_order_id GROUP BY app_user.au_userid
```

2.

```
SELECT COUNT (app_user.au_id) FROM  app_user JOIN orders ON app_user.au_id = orders.o_au_id GROUP BY app_user.au_id
```

the following query no.3 doesn't working..
3.

```
SELECT app_user.au_userid, (SELECT COUNT (app_user.au_id) FROM app_user JOIN orders ON app_user.au_id = orders.o_au_id GROUP BY app_user.au_id) AS total, SUM (order_detail.od_quantity), (order_detail.od_quantity*SUM (order_detail.od_subtotal)) AS total_amount FROM app_user JOIN orders ON app_user.au_id = orders.o_au_id JOIN order_detail ON orders.o_id = order_detail.od_order_id GROUP BY app_user.au_userid
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Combine how? Show us some sample result from each query, and also the combined result.

Comment: you could please format query 3 properly, i.e line breaks, indentation etc. im not reading that like it is

Comment: i want to conbine just like query no.3

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method uses `COUNT(distinct)`:

```
SELECT o.o_au_id, COUNT (DISTINCT o.o_id) AS num_orders,
       SUM(od.od_quantity),
       SUM(od.od_quantity * od.od_subtotal) AS total_amount
FROM orders o JOIN 
     order_detail od
     ON o.o_id = od.od_order_id
GROUP BY o.o_au_id;
```

Notes:

- You don't need `app_users`, because you have the user id in the orders table.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- For calculating the total amount, you should be doing the multiplication before the summation.
- To get the number of orders, use `count(distinct)`.